# Know Cloudrun went into OOM

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-run

I have a case where I want to know if the request sent to cloudrun was terminated due to timeout being hit or due to memory limit being hit.

In both the cases I am getting 503 with "Service Unavailable" as response content.

Comment: In both case, the client will see a crash server side. However, on server side, you have the detail in the log. Normally, the client does not need to know the reason: there is a crash. That's all!

Comment: @ankit, does above comment answers your question? or do you still have any questions?

Comment: So basically its not possible to know the how the crash happened right? I assumed that cloudrun should know if the crash was due connection breakage between container and the application running or due to the resource limit of the contiainer itself. That's because OOMs should be detected above the layer in which our application runs. So if cloudrun wanted, they could add info in response about that. I was just making sure I did not miss anything google had in their docs.

Comment: @ankit Can you have a look at below answer and let me know if you have additional queries?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As mentioned by @guillaume blaquiere,

> In both cases, the client will see a crash server side. However, on the server side, you have the details in the log. Normally, the client does not need to know the reason: there is a crash. That's all!

To answer your question

> So basically its not possible to know the how the crash happened right?

You may check the cloud run logs for detailed information about errors and differentiate the error. Based on the error you can try the steps mentioned in [troubleshoot document](https://cloud.google.com/run/docs/troubleshooting#timeout-503)

And also you can monitor the memory used by `cloud run` by using [monitoring tools](https://cloud.google.com/monitoring/api/metrics_gcp#gcp-run) which may help you in predicting memory outages.